# How to understand the intrinsic definition fo the projective tangent space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, tangent-spaces

**Introduction**

I am a physicist struggling with some basic definitions and concepts from algebraic geometry. Therefore I apologize if I make mistakes, I'm just learning! By the way, English is not my mother tongue, sorry if I made grammar or vocabulary mistakes!

**Tangent space to a point**

Let $X$ be a projective variety ($X\subset \mathbb{P}^n$). The intrinsic definition of the tangent space to $X$ at $p\in X$ is $T_p(X)=(m_p/ m_p^2)^\star$, where $m_p$ is the maximum ideal of functions vanishing at p. Equivalently, one can define $T_p(X)= Z(\{d_pf ~|~ f\in I(X) \text{ homogeneous } \})$, where $Z(\{f_i\}_{i\in J\subset \mathbb{N}})=\{a\in \mathbb{P} | f_i(a)=0 \forall i\in J\}$.

**Question**

Interpretation of $T_p(X)=(m_p/ m_p^2)^\star$ : I don't understand the meaning of this definition. I understand, following $T_p(X)= Z(\{d_pf ~|~ f(t)=0 ~\forall t\in X\})$, that the tangent space to a point is the space where directional derivatives vanish, but I can't link this insight to the so-called intrinsic definition.

**Edit 1**
According to the reference in Qi Zhu's comment, here is what I have understood. Could you please tell me if I'm right ?

Derivatives around a point p are functions defined by two properties.

First, they must take something from $m_p$ in order to be polynomials and to be well defined at p, and send it to $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore they are first defined as functions $m_p \rightarrow \mathbb{R} : f \rightarrow f'(p)$.

Second, they must obey Leibniz rule, which expresses that if f(p)=g(p)=0, then (fg)'(p)=0. In other words, if f and g are polynomials and p=0, then (fg)'(p)=0. It means that the monomials terms of degree $\geq$2 of a polynomial won't change anything to the result of partial derivatives at such a point. Therefore, we can "drop" them, saying that two polynomials whose monomials terms of degree 1 are the same are equivalent. Then, derivatives at a point p are defined by functions $m_p/m_p^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} : f \rightarrow f'(p)$, that is, elements of $(m_p/m_p^2)^*$

I'm sure I was careless in the second part, but I'm not able to be more rigorous than that. If I'm right in the way to think it, I would appreciate and accept as an answer a rigorous correction of this explanation of what I have understood

Comment: You mean $(\mathfrak{m}_p/\mathfrak{m}_p^2)^*$. I would try to explain but I cannot explain it better than Ravi Vakil in his Rising Sea, p. 331ff.

Comment: Thanks a lot for referring this masterpiece to me. Since I'm not really familiar with modern algebraic geometry (but rather familiar to Italian fashion), I'm not sure to understand everything. What I didn't understand is the $m^2$ part. Why do we quotient by $m^2$ ? Is it just something that we noticed? Such as "oh we drop linear terms every time we compute the tangent space, then let's drop them in the definition"?

Comment: I mean it's not "just something we noticed", it's the essence of tangent spaces: We only want to capture the linear information because it is the easiest to work with, so we drop higher-dimensional terms.

Comment: Your comments helped me to understand it better. I edited my post, could you please, if I'm not asking too much, give me your opinion ? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: From a quick glance it looks OK :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot :)